# Backup SSRS Encryption Keys Using Powershell

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I have made the following script from google for backing up the SSRS Encryption keys:

```
cls
$pwd = "sa@123@123"
$SSRSClass = Get-Wmiobject -namespace "root\microsoft\sqlserver\reportserver\rs_BPSSRS\v10\admin" -class "MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting"

$key = $SSRSClass.BackupEncryptionKey($pwd)
$stream = [System.IO.File]::Create("c:\\SSRS.snk", $key.KeyFile.Length)
$stream.Write($key.KeyFile, 0, $key.KeyFile.Length)
$stream.Close()
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'BackupEn
cryptionKey'.
At line:5 char:38
+ $key = $SSRSClass.BackupEncryptionKey <<<< ($results)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (BackupEncryptionKey:String) [], RuntimeEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception calling "Create" with "2" argument(s): "Positive number required.
Parameter name: bufferSize"
At line:6 char:35
+ $stream = [System.IO.File]::Create <<<< ("c:\\SSRS.snk", $key.KeyFile.Length)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:14
+ $stream.Write <<<< ($key.KeyFile, 0, $key.KeyFile.Length)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Write:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:14
+ $stream.Close <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I'm using powershell v2. I tried finding about this but no luck. There are around 50+ SSRS servers in our environment and doing backup manually is tiresome. Hence, we came up with this automation. Kindly provide your comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using WMI to backup RS key might not be so efficient. You may try the below script that I found at http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2015/05/backup-report-server-encryption-key.html

```powershell
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     Script : Backup_RSKey.ps1 
#     Author : Som DT.
#    Purpose : Backup Report Server Encryption Key with Powershell
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     Syntax : Powershell .\Backup_RSKey.ps1 -InstanceName <InstanceName> -PassWord <Password> -BackupLocation <BackupLocation> 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Example : Powershell .\Backup_RSKey.ps1 -InstanceName "MSSQLSERVER" -PassWord "rsdal@2015" -BackupLocation "C:\temp"
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

param ( 
    [string]$InstanceName="MSSQLSERVER", 
    [string]$PassWord="rsdal@2015", 
    [string]$BackupLocation="C:\temps" 
)

cls
$FileTimestamp=$(get-date).tostring("yyyyMMddHHmmss")


function Backup-RSKey([string]$InstanceName , [string]$PassWord, [string]$BackupLocation)
{
    Trap {
        echo  "Failure : $($Error[0].Exception.Message)" 
        return 
    }

    $KeyFile="${BackupLocation}\KEY_$InstanceName_$FileTimestamp.snk" 

    echo "Backing up to file : $KeyFile" 

    $Error.Clear() 

    Out-String -InputObject( echo "Y" | RSKeyMgmt.exe -e -f"$KeyFile" -p"$PasWord" -i"$InstanceName")  

    if (!(Test-Path "$KeyFile") )
    {
        return "Failure : Error occured while backing up [$KeyFile]."
    }
    else 
    {
        return "Success"
    }

}


$Output=Backup-RSKey "$InstanceName"  "$PassWord"   "$BackupLocation"

echo $Output

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-- End of Program
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```